Method of characteristic
I have the equation
$$
\partial_t u(t,x) + \sin(t) \partial_x u(t,x) +\cos(t) u(t,x) = 0.
$$
with a initial condition $u(0,x)=f(x)$.
I want to solve this using the method of characteristics. First I consider just the equation
$$
\partial_t u(t,x) + \sin(t) \partial_x u(t,x)=0,
$$
parametrizing by $s$ we get the equations
$$
\frac{\mathrm d t(s)}{\mathrm d s} = 1, \quad \frac{\mathrm d x(s)}{\mathrm d s} = \sin(t(s)),
$$
which has the solutions
$$
t(s) = s, \quad x(s) = c_1 - \cos(s).
$$
with $c_1$ being a constant (I've determined the constant in $t(s)$ to be zero since we have the initial conditions at $t=0$).
Thus the solution is $u(t,x) = f(x + \cos(t)).$
Now along the characteristic curves the PDE reduces to an ODE
$$
\frac{\mathrm d u(s)}{\mathrm d s} + \cos(s) u(s)=0.
$$
the argument for this is that
$$
\frac{\mathrm d u(s)}{\mathrm d s} = \frac{\mathrm d u(t(s),x(s))}{\mathrm ds} = \partial_{t(s)} u(t(s),x(s)) + \sin(t(s)) \partial_{x(s)} u(t(s),x(s)).
$$
the ODE has the solution
$$
u(s) = e^{-\sin(s)} c_2.
$$
It's not now obvious to me where I went wrong, I assume that probrably we cannot take $\cos(t) = \cos(s)$ when we are along the characteristic curves. But how do I solve the equation correctly?

The function $u(s)$ satisfies the differential equation
$$
\frac{du(s)}{ds}=-u(s)\cos(t(s))=-u(s)\cos(s), \tag{1}
$$
where the second equality follows from $t(s)=s$. The solution to $(1)$ is
$$
u(s)=u(0)\,e^{-\sin(s)}. \tag{2}
$$
Now
$$
u(0)=u(t(0),x(0))=u(0,c_1-1)=f(c_1-1). \tag{3}
$$
Solving
$$
t(s) = s, \qquad x(s) = c_1 - \cos(s) \tag{4}
$$
for $c_1$ and $s$, we get
$$
s = t, \qquad c_1 = x+\cos(t). \tag{5}
$$
Combining $(2), (3)$ and $(5)$, we finally obtain
$$
u(t,x)=f(x+\cos(t)-1)\,e^{-\sin(t)}. \tag{6}
$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\sin(t)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=-\cos(t)u$$
Characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{\sin(t)}=\frac{du}{-\cos(t)u}=ds$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{\sin(t)}$ :
$$x+\cos(t)=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from  solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{-\cos(t)u}$ :
$$u\:e^{\sin(t)}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on the form of implicit equation $c_2=\Phi(c_1)$ is :
$$u\:e^{\sin(t)}=\Phi\big(x+\cos(t)\big)$$
$\Phi$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to the initial condition).
$$u(x,t)=e^{-\sin(t)}\Phi\big(x+\cos(t)\big)$$
With condition $u(0,x)=f(x)$ :
$$u(0,x)=e^{-\sin(0)}\Phi\big(x+\cos(0)\big)=\Phi\big(x+1\big)=f(x)$$
This implies $\Phi(X)=f(X-1)$ .
The function $\Phi$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=x+\cos(t)$
$$u(x,t)=e^{-\sin(t)}f\big(x+\cos(t)-1\big)$$
This is the particular solution of the PDE which satisfies the initial solution.
